Cannot remove languages from Swift string catalog
I've got quite a problem as I've created a Localizible file with String catalog for my iOS app. For testing it out I've added lots of different languages and they all appeared in App settings.
However, I need to remove most of them and they are still visible in the settings.
What I tried so far:
I have deleted EVERYTHING that had word localizable, localizations and etc. From Project Info also all the languages were removed and left only English and French.
I also deleted my app, restarted the phone, downloaded the version without localizations from the app store and then install debug version (languages still appeared)




Did you clean before rebuilding? That worked for me. Some localisation-related files are not deleted from the output when you remove a localisation and rebuild, apparently.

Wow, I was going mad and this helped! Thanks a lot!

See also Xcode 11 - Removing localization

You should clean before rebuilding. The old .lproj files will remain in the app bundle if you don't clean, and apparently this is what the settings app uses to determine what languages to show.
